# why i am getting this error- unknown column 'customers.c_id' in field list

Tags: mysql, database

i am getting this error
unknown column 'customers.c_id' in field list
when i am using `FULL JOIN` command on the tables

I have two tables

**1-customers 2-orders**

```
Host: localhost
Database: abcd
    SQL query: SELECT * FROM `customers` LIMIT 0, 30 ; 
Rows: 6

c_id    c_name  city    pincode
1   gagan   ghaziabad   201005
2   raman   delhi       20200
3   manish  punjab      10123
4   vinay   jammu       31201
5   praveen kerala      40001
6   raghav  goa         10200


Host: localhost
Database: abcd
    SQL query: SELECT * FROM `orders` LIMIT 0, 30 ; 
Rows: 4

orderId c_id    orderDate
1102    5   2014-02-05
1109    2   2015-01-15
1012    3   2016-03-10
1117    7   2017-05-25
```

and my sql command is:-

```
    SELECT customers.c_id,orders.orderId,customers.c_name
FROM customers
FULL JOIN orders
ON
customers.c_id=order.c_id;
```

[sql command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Jtj.png)

Error:-

> ERROR 1054 <42S22>: Unknown column 'customers.c_id' in 'field list'

Comment: MySQL does not support full join.

Comment: can you remove full join and run it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `MySQL` doesn't support a `FULL JOIN` you need to `UNION` your query with a `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.

```
SELECT c.c_id, o.orderId, c.c_name
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.c_id = o.c_id
UNION ALL
SELECT c.c_id, o.orderId, c.c_name
FROM customers c
RIGHT JOIN orders o ON c.c_id = o.c_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support `full join`, not even syntactically.  So your query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT customers.c_id, orders.orderId, customers.c_name
FROM customers `FULL` INNER JOIN
     orders
     ON customers.c_id = orders.c_id;
```

Hence, the table called `customers` has the alias `FULL` in the query.  There are no columns in `customers`.

I should add that there is no need for `FULL JOIN` for this query.  Assuming you have reasonable foreign key relationships between the tables, a `LEFT JOIN` will get all customers, even those without orders:

```
SELECT c.c_id, o.orderId, c.c_name
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.c_id = o.c_id;
```

Comment: @GaganKumar . . . `LEFT JOIN` really should be sufficient for this.